# Publish profile with MSBuild 2022 not working

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, msbuild, visual-studio-2022, .net-framework-version

MsBuild.exe MyProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugType=None /p:Optimize=True /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyPublishProfile /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0"

We used to run above command to build and published webapp using MsBuild.exe. This is working fine whenever we are using MsBuild packaged along with VS 2019.
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin

However, as soon as we are using MsBuild that came along with VS2022, it is compiling project but not publishing.

Can anyone provide some light why publish is not working when running above command with MsBuild VS 2022?

Note: This project is targeting .Net framework 4.7.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now. Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 2):

This link tell you that MSBuild 17.0 shipped with Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/whats-new-msbuild-17-0?view=vs-2019

You can refer to the following link to solve the problem:
First, enter “msbuild -ver” in the command line tool to view the version of msbuild.

[image]

Then change the command “/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 “ to “/p:VisualStudioVersion=17.2.1 “.

It works in my test.

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the version but no luck. It's same behavior with version 16.0. For both cases Build is successful but it's not publishing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "Publish" target. The following does work for me using MSBuild from VS2022 for my .NET 7.0 project:

```
MSbuild.exe "C:\SomePath\SomeProject.csproj" -p:Configuration="YourProjectConfiguration" -restore -t:Publish -p:PublishProfile="NameOfPublishProfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just gave up on this taking all the parameters stored in publish profile and pass it manually, this seems to work with VS 2022

```
dotnet publish "C:\SomePath\SomeProject.csproj" -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true -p:PublishReadyToRun=true -p:PublishDir=relative\newDirPublish
```

Comment: OP asked for MSBuild, not dotnet CLI.
I am looking for the same problem, i.e. MSBuild for the .net framework

Comment: Yes you're right. with MSBuild this worked for me, just had the issue with sdk-style-projects (.net core) which need to be published with dotnet-cli (as far as i know).

msbuild somproject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="PROD Publish" /p:Configuration=Release

Comment: again as OP mentioned, it is for .NET Framework so this answers doesn't covers the problem statement